# How to create a .dbf file using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, dbf

I am trying this to make a select and it works just fine

```
string str = 
    "SELECT * FROM FREE RIGHT JOIN TestTest ON FREE.DOCNO = TestTest.DOCNO";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(str, odbconn);
da.Fill(dt);
```

I am trying this to create a .dbf and i get this OdbcException :

```
string str0 = "Create Table Persons (Name char(50), City char(50), Phone char(20), Zip decimal(5))";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(str0, odbconn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] Syntax error in field definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by `Zip decimal(5)`, as the ODBC dBase driver doesn't like it. Off the top of my head, and after a quick google, I couldn't come up with a syntax it *would* tolerate. It does accept it quite merrily if you use the OleDb provider instead, as follows:

```
using (var dBaseConnection = new OleDbConnection(
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " +
    @" Data Source=C:\Users\RobertWray\Documents\dBase; " +
    @"Extended Properties=dBase IV"))
{
    dBaseConnection.Open();

    string createTableSyntax = 
        "Create Table Person " +
        "(Name char(50), City char(50), Phone char(20), Zip decimal(5))";
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand(createTableSyntax, dBaseConnection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**One question though:** Are you *sure* that you want to create the Zip column as a decimal? Not being a US resident I'm not 100% confident on this information, but, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code_prefixes) ZIP codes can start with a `0`. Storing them as a numeric datatype won't allow you to accurately represent that.

My code for creating the table via ODBC:

```
using (var dBaseConnection = new OdbcConnection(@"Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=C:\Users\RobertWray\Documents\dBase;"))
{
    dBaseConnection.Open();

    string str0 = "Create Table Person2 (Name char(50), City char(50), Phone char(20))";
    var cmd = new OdbcCommand(str0, dBaseConnection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: i did that zip decimal(5) just for testing. i still got an issue with that OleDbConnection, the way it is working for me is 
string pathFiles = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "DB");
string strconn = "Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;" +  "Dbq="+pathFiles+";";
 OdbcConnection odbconn = new OdbcConnection(strconn);

Comment: @jane, sorry, I don't understand what you mean by your comment. Your table creation SQL works a treat for me, both via OleDb and Odbc. It works in its entirety via OleDb and with the `Zip decimal(5)` removed for Odbc. It might be a good idea to increase the size of the code sample you show in your question! =)

Comment: @jane, there's something else wrong/different then. I've copied the code I used to create the table via ODBC into my answer - can you try that and see if it works for you (obviously change the path! =), and then perhaps tweak it into your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use vfpoledb provider and field type `NUMERIC` instead of `DECIMAL`.

```
string ConnStr1 = @"Provider =vfpoledb; Data Source = C:\MyDataSource; Collating Sequence =machine;
```